# Fast calculation of number partition offset

Tags: combinatorics

For a number partition of width x, is there a fast way to calculate offset k without recurring/calculating the previous possibilities?

A number partition implies to have the left slot value greater or equal to the one we are looking at.

e.g:
6,5,5,4 works

but

6,5,4,5 doesn't because the 2nd 5 is greater than 4. [wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory))

So the logic is to get from the highest numbers combination to the lowest possible values combination.

For example, for an array of length 5 with a maximum value of 6, which sum is 21, gives:

```
6,6,6,2,1 //offset 0
6,6,5,3,1 //offset 1
6,6,5,2,2
6,6,4,4,1
6,6,4,3,2
6,6,3,3,3
6,5,5,4,1
6,5,5,3,2
6,5,4,4,2 //offset 8
6,5,4,3,3
6,4,4,4,3
5,5,5,5,1
5,5,5,4,2
5,5,5,3,3
5,5,4,4,3
5,4,4,4,4 //offset 15
```

There are 16 solutions for these parameters.

If I am interested in knowing what the offset 8 looks like, do I have to calculate all the previous solutions first or is there an existing formula?

Thanks

Comment: I don't know what you are asking. What is this offset? How is it calculated? What does the array you wrote even mean?

Comment: Ok I edit my post to add those info.

Comment: I still don't know what is happening to the array. Sure, every tow sums to $21$, but what is the mechanism for going from one row to the next? What is the goal here? What does "offset" mean?

Comment: is my question clearer now?

Comment: I now understand your question, But I don't know of any simple way of calculating the offsets, sorry.

Comment: you are welcome :)